# If I make a script that requires root privileges, do I need to put sudo in the script too?

Tags: installation, drivers, scripts, sudo

I'm working on an installer script for the latest ATI drivers (as they are not in repo) and was wondering if I need to include sudo in the script, because it will be needed for the install.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

no, if you need root privileges you call the script with sudo.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure, and wanted to check before testing it :D

Comment: @ChrisWeigle: In general, this is correct. However, there might be cases where you want sudo in the script itself. How well this works depends on your sudo configuration, since sudo might or might ask for a password. The case I most commonly use is for editing text files. I use `vim`, which I call `vi` out of longstanding habit. On my system, `vi` is actually a script that runs `sudo vim` if the file isn't otherwise writeable. (By the way, such a script is for experienced users only, as you can break your system with it if you aren't careful.)

Comment: I understand Scott, but, you probably also realize, as an experienced user, that is a dangerous script indeed ;)

Answer (score 1):

All commands in a script are run as the calling user. So if I write this script:

> #### /home/user/my_script
>
> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> echo "I am running as root" > /root/status.txt
> ```

I can successfully produce a file containing "I am running as root" at `/root/status.txt` by executing either:

```
user@host$ sudo /home/user/my_script
```

Or as the superuser:

```
root@host$ /home/user/my_script
```